# Domain & Computer name change problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-sbs

Client has two domains and wants there only to be one. Domain A's DC is an sbs2k machine, and Domain B's is a 2k3 running at Windows 2000 Mixed functional level. Along with changing the domain name I will need to change the computer name as it is identical to one already on domain A. I read that it's required to change 2k3's functional level to 2003 in order to make name changes changes using netdom. So I believe I'm unable to carry out task without a clean install.
What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest your best option is to demote the DC in domain B, rename it, join it to domain A and then promote it to being a DC in domain A.

Otherwise, even if you are able to change the name, you are still going to have issues with that machine being a DC in domain B. Do it properly first time and you will have less issues in the long term.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not thinking about that. Thanks so much man.

Answer (score 1):

You can only raise the domain functional level to 2003 if all domain controllers are running the 2K3 OS.

You'll need to do a clean install of 2K3 on Domain A and dcpromo it.

Comment: My bad, forgot to clarify on that in the question. I did already know that having to change the functional level was not going to work having the sbs2k DC. Thanks though!